# Galaxy S2 restarts

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, connection-issues

My Galaxy S2 restarts occassionally. In addition, it sometimes loses connection with my service provider (even when the signal strength is good). I just have to switch it off and back on again.

I have upgraded the software to the latest version. Everything else works fine. No problem with making calls, connecting to wifi etc.

Is this a hardware or software issue?

Comment: I just saw my S2 in mid reboot when I happened to glance at it on my desk. What's going on? OS auto update?

Comment: did you clear dalvik cache ? did you wiped data from previous rom ? sometimes when you flash a new rom provider info can get purged, have you tried searching your provider's website for any info on adding it back ?